# c++11 member function returns vector of raw pointers from vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am starting using c++11 features and I like to use smart pointers only to own the objects. Here is my class:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    vector<MyObject*> get_objs() const;

  private:
    vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>> m_objs;
};
```

The semantics is that `MyClass` owns a serial of `MyObject` which are created through `make_unique`(). `get_objs()` returns a vector of raw pointers in order for various callers to update the objects. Because those callers do not own the objects, so the function does not return `vector<unique_ptr>.`

But this means I need to implement `get_objs()` like this:

```
vector<MyObjects*> MyClass::get_objs() const
{
  vector<MyObjects*> ret;
  for (auto obj : my_objs) {
    ret.push_back(obj->get());
  }
  return ret;
}
```

My concern is `get_objs()` is called fairly often, each time there is an overhead to construct this raw pointer vector.

Is there something I could do here? If there is no c++11 tricks to save the overhead, should I just use type `vector<MyObject*>` for `m_objs` in the first place?

```
UPDATE 1
```

Jonathan Wakely's solution using `operator[]` improves mine so that caller can access individual object directly.

Is there any other solution? I do not mind go over all the places calling `get_objs(),` but like to see if there is even better solution.

Another note - I cannot use BOOST, just some restriction I have to live with.

Comment: For a start you can use `ret.reserve(m_objs.size())` to pre-allocate the right number of elements.

Comment: If you put the raw pointers inside another vector, they are no longer unique. What if the vector you return is kept around longer than the `MyClass` object is? Then the pointers in the returned vector will point to unallocated memory. And you should not just look at the new smart pointers as some container that automatically delete the pointer when it goes out of scope, you should look at it more from an ownership point of view.

Comment: If you're going to be sharing the objects, you should probably use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Your getter is `const` - so what's wrong with returning a const reference to `m_objs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
  public:
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> const& get_objs() const {
     return m_objs;
   }

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> m_objs;
};
```

a `const std::unique_ptr<MyObject>&` cannot steal ownership, and is not the same as a `std::unique_ptr<const MyObject>`.  A `const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>&` can only grant `const` access to its data.

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) I would instead do this:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
   std::span<std::unique_ptr<MyObject> const> get_objs() const {
     return {m_objs.begin(), m_objs.end()};
   }

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> m_objs;
};
```

which hides the implementation detail of "I am storing it in a vector" while exposing "I am storing it contiguously".

Prior to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), I advise finding or writing your own `span` type if you have the budget.  They are quite useful.

Comment: +1, I think it's worth mentioning that ownership cannot be stolen from the `const unique_ptr<MyObject>` elements in the const vector, but using `get()` you can still get a non-const `MyObject*` from them to update the objects, as the OP wants.

Answer (score 6):

For a start you can use `ret.reserve(m_objs.size())` to pre-allocate the right number of elements.

Alternatively, don't return a vector for callers to iterate over directly, but expose a vector-like interface instead:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    struct iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    MyObject* operator[](size_t n) { return m_objs[n].get(); }

  private:
    vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>> m_objs;
};
```

This allows the callers to modify the objects directly, rather than getting a container of pointers.

Comment: Why is `operator[]` returning a pointer, and why is there not a `const` variant of it.

Comment: It returns a pointer because that's the `value_type` of the vector in the original code, and the same type as `iterator_traits<MyClass::iterator>::value_type` (although that's not shown above :-)). There's no const overload because the stated purpose of the OP's API is "in order for various callers to update the objects" so without more information there's no need for a variant that doesn't allow updating the objects.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I picked Yakk's suggestion because of less editing.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Boost, try indirect_iterator (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html). You need to define iterator, begin and end in your class:

```
typedef boost::indirect_iterator<vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>::iterator> iterator;
iterator begin() { return make_indirect_iterator(m_objs.begin()); }
```

Then your class exposes iterator, the value of which is reference (not pointer!) to `MyObject`. You can iterate and access the elements of the vector directly.

Comment: I would advise it too, but unfortunately the OP stated "Another note - I cannot use BOOST, just some restriction I have to live with."

Comment: Then an option is to write manually the equivalent of indirect_iterator.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I think something like [Jonathan Wakely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25506288/3549027) is the way to go. But since you asked for more possibilities, another one is to use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    const vector<shared_ptr<MyObject>>& get_objs() const {
        return m_objs;
    }

  private:
    vector<shared_ptr<MyObject>> m_objs;
};
```

This improves the original code in two ways:

1. There is no longer any need to build up a new vector in `get_objs`; you can just return a reference to the one you have.
2. You no longer need to worry about wild pointers in the case where a caller keeps the return value alive longer than the object that returned it--`shared_ptr` ensures the pointed-to objects aren't deleted until all references have been released.

On another note, `get_objs` arguably should not be `const`. Calling code can't modify the vector itself, but it *can* modify the `MyObject`s it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is not to return any objects at all and encapsulate how you are storing the data (tell don't ask).
Usually when you get the items you end up iterating through them all, so it makes sense to wrap that up in the class and pass in a function you want your objects to pass through.

The non boost way will be something like

```
void MyClass::VisitItems(std::function<void, MyObject&> f)
{
    for (auto obj : my_objs)
    {
        f(*obj);
    }
}
```