# How to ensure constness of the returning vector<unique_ptr>

Tags: c++, c++11

I asked related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506191/c11-member-function-returns-vector-of-raw-pointers-from-vector-of-unique-ptr). Now it is a little subtler.

Here is the code:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    const vector<unique_ptr<MyObject> >& get_const_objs() const;

  private:
    vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>> m_objs;
};
```

My intention is that the returned vector from get_const_objs() is read-only, but the problem is because the elements of the vector are not const, so caller still can change the individual elements, e.g.

```
const vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>>& objs = pMyClass->get_const_objs();
unique_ptr<MyObject> p = move(objs[0]);
```

My solution is to insert const to the vector:

```
const vector<const unique_ptr<MyObject> >& get_const_objs() const;
```

But this leads to a boring implementation of get_const_objs() which I copy each element to a new vector:

```
const vector<const unique_ptr<MyObjects>>& MyClass::get_const_objs() const
{
  vector<const unique_ptr<MyObjects>> ret;
  for (const auto &obj : my_objs) {
    ret.push_back(obj);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Yes, I can add iterator interface to MyClass. Is there any other solution?

I have a restriction: BOOST is not available. But I like to know BOOST solution if really there is good one just using standard.

Comment: Using `const T` as the type in a vector violates its requirements. And `unique_ptr<MyObject> p = move(objs[0]);` doesn't compile.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to find a way to prevent changes to the objects being held by the `vector`. If so, your title is a bit misleading.

Comment: You already can't modify the elements inside a vector via a const reference to that vector. Are you talking about how to prevent modifications to the `MyObject`s the pointers point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>>& objs = pMyClass->get_const_objs();
unique_ptr<MyObject> p = move(objs[0]);
```

[You cannot do it](http://ideone.com/CktPfJ), So you don't have to worry!

Since `objs` is `const vector<> &`, the element of this vector is also treated as `const`. Therefore, you cannot "move" it; can you move const objects?

Comment: yes, you are right. I did not really compile the code and should have. I need to refresh my knowledge on constness of vector and its elements.

Answer (score 1):

A (little) better solution is to return `std::vector<const MyObject*>` and not expose `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::vector<const MyObject*> get_const_objs() const
{
    std::vector<const MyObject*> res;
    res.reserve(my_objs.size());
    for (const auto& obj : my_objs) {
        res.push_back(obj.get());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Instead of recreating the vector each time, you may have this vector as member, but then you need to keep the vectors synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Custom iterators seem to be the easiest way to go, simply expose only an iterator dereferencing to const MyObject&

```
class ConstObjectIter {
public:
    ...
    const MyObject& operator* () const { return **m_it; }
    const MyObject* operator->() const { return &**this; }
    ConstIter& operator++() { ++m_it; return *this; }
    ...
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject> >::const_iterator m_it, m_end;
}
```

initialise `m_it, m_end` with `m_objs.begin(), m_objs.end()` resp.